# Using Apache Knox in non Hadoop app

Tags: knox-gateway

Does it makes sense to use Knox (+LDAP) as authentication proxy to application that is not using Hadoop at all?

I'm new to this domain and have heard about such possibility but I don't quite get it. Maybe there are some viable alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely ! you can use Apache Knox without Hadoop. I use it to secure my  Raspberry Pi Motion setup, this is a link to the blog post (it is still work in progress but you'll get an idea) [Securing Raspberry Pi Security Camera (or UIs) using Apache Knox](http://sandeepmore.com/blog/2017/06/28/securing_raspberry_pi_security_camera/)

Comment: Hey, can you ping me once your blog post is completed? I'm Knox newbie..

Comment: This is great!  Can anyone add more context to this discussion?  What about a simple example where the backend is an arbitrary web service or S3 bucket?

Comment: Here is a super simple example of how to add a weather api web service using Apache Knox https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KNOX/2015/12/17/Adding+a+service+to+Apache+Knox